# Render part of page on dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a chart on my main view which I would like to update partially when a dropdown selects different values.

The page renders correctly the first time, but when I select a new value in the dropdown, then "-PnlChart.cshtml" replace the entire page. I want just the chart portion to be updated.

How to I ensure that?

> _PnlChart.cshtml

```
<img src="@Url.Action("CreateTraderPnlChart3")" width="600" height="600" align="middle" vspace="50" />
```

> My mainview Index.cshtml:

```
  <div class="w3-half">

        @{ Html.RenderAction("PeriodSelection");}

          @Html.DropDownList("PeriodSelection",
                    new SelectList((string[])Session["Periods"]),
                    (string)Session["Period"],
                    new
                    {
                        onchange = "document.location.href = '/Employee/PeriodSelection?dropdownlistReturnValue=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"
                    })
        </div>
```

> My controller:

```
    public ActionResult PeriodSelection(string dropdownlistReturnValue) // dont know what dropdownlistReturnValue is doing?
    {
        Session["Period"] = dropdownlistReturnValue;
        return PartialView("~/Views/Employee/_PnlChart.cshtml");
    }
```

Comment: `location.href` navigates to a new page. You need to use ajax is you want to stay on the same page and update the DOM

Comment: I created ajax version but am still getting problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343295/render-part-of-page-on-dropdown-selection-part-2