# Render part of page on dropdown selection part 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is a follow on to similar question but taking suggestions into account.

[Render part of page on dropdown selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341262/render-part-of-page-on-dropdown-selection)

I have a chart on my main view which I would like to update partially when a dropdown selects different values.

The page renders correctly the first time, but when I select a new value in the dropdown, then I think the .submit script is failing in the script .submit() because when I put a break on window.submitAjaxForm it is never reached.

> _PnlChart.cshtml

```
<img src="@Url.Action("CreateTraderPnlChart3")" width="600" height="600" align="middle" vspace="50" />
```

> My mainview Index.cshtml:

```
  <div class="w3-half">


    <div id="ExportDiv">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PnlChart");}
    </div>

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetEnvironment",
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "Environment", "" } }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "ExportDiv" }, new { id = "ajaxForm" } ))
        {
            @Html.DropDownList("PeriodSelection",
                new SelectList((string[])Session["Periods"]),
                (string)Session["Period"],
                new
                { onchange = "submitAjaxForm()" })
        }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('form#ajaxForm').submit(function(event) {
       eval($(this).attr('onsubmit')); return false;
        });

    window.submitAjaxForm = function(){
        $('form#ajaxForm').submit();
         }
    </script>

    </div>
```

> My controller:

```
    public ActionResult PeriodSelection(string dropdownlistReturnValue) // dont know what dropdownlistReturnValue is doing?
    {
        Session["Period"] = dropdownlistReturnValue;
        return PartialView("~/Views/Employee/_PnlChart.cshtml");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code,

> eval($(this).attr('onsubmit')); return false;

I am not sure what you were intending to do here. But from your question, i assume you wanted to do a form submission. But that line will not submit the form. The expression `$(this).attr('onsubmit')` is going to return `undefined` as your form does not have an `onsubmit` attribute defined.

But you already have the form submit code in your other method (`submitAjaxForm`). So if you simply remove the `$('form#ajaxForm').submit` handler (apparently it does not do anything useful), your code will work. When you change the dropdown, it will make an ajax form submission.

But your form action is set to `GetEnvironment` action method. That means your ajax form submission will be to that action method. In your question you have a different action method which returns the updated chart content. It does not makes sense!

I personally prefer to write handwritten ajax calls instead of relying on the ajax action helper methods. The below is the code i would probably use (*Except the dropdownlist code. read further*)

```
<div id="ExportDiv">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PnlChart");}
</div>
@Html.DropDownList("PeriodSelection",
        new SelectList((string[])Session["Periods"]),
        (string)Session["Period"], new
        {  data_charturl = Url.Action("PeriodSelection","Home")})
```

Now listen to the change event of the SELECT element.

```
$(function(){

  $("#PeriodSelection").change(function(){
     var v = $(this).val();
     var url=$(this).data("charturl")+'?dropdownlistReturnValue='+v;
     $("#ExportDiv").load(url);
  });

});
```

You should consider using the a view model to pass the Dropdownlist data. Why not use the DropDownListFor helper method ? It looks much clean, Mixing a lot of C# code (See all the session casting and all.) makes it kind of dirty IMHO.

Comment: I made those exact changes. It renders whole view properly on start-up. Then on dropdown selection I do get into PeriodSelection, BUT then the partial view area goes completely blank (my original chart is lost too).

Comment: That means your ajax call is working, but the response from the ajax call is not rendering the chart you want. Check the browser network tab and see the ajax call's response. May be your action method code has some issues.

Comment: OK. Can I pass selection Text rather than Index? How do I do that? Does .val alwasy give the index?

Comment: `val()` method returns the selected option value attribute value, not the index! . If the value attribute is not there, it will return the text.(This is what happening in your case. If you open up browser network tab, you will be able toes that in the ajax call.

Comment: Yes! my mistake. But returning PartialView does not appear to load my _PnlChart.cshtml (as that call has c# where I have break points)

Comment: As I mentioned in my earlier comment, you. Red to check why your action method is returning what you want. You can simply open the Ajax call request in a new browser tab(copy the URL and paste in a new tab) and that may give you some info why it is failing.

Comment: @{Console.WriteLine("");}
<img src="@Url.Action("CreateTraderPnlChart3")" width="600" height="600" align="middle" vspace="50" /> I can step through to the Console, but when I step on the img line I get no error but the debugger doees NOT go into the action code. The cshtml file this line is in does not appear in sources of Firefox debugger so I can't step through it there...

Comment: Try to access the image source url in a new browser tab (`/CreateTraderPnlChart3`)

Comment: I get the usual Firefox "do you want to save file" dialog box I get for downloads...

Comment: Make sure you have proper code to **Render** the chart image. Without seeing it, it is hard to say. Ideally you should be seeing the image in the browser when you try to access the image source.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772059/razor-second-chart-will-not-display-at-all